# Should I use a mutex for TCP client send or code my own queuing mechanism?

Tags: delphi, mutex, indy10

Delphi XE2, Indy V10, Windows 7 Pro - but I think I have a general conceptual problem.

1. Indy's TCP client is synchronous - it uses blocking calls.
2. However parts of my application are asynchronous - I want to send data over TCP and wait for a response when 
   A) the 3rd party serial port component reports input from the serial port (it appears to be asynchronous & run in it's own thread, posting messages to my application's main form's Windows message queue) and 
   B) when one of several timers expires (also asynchronous)
3. My application's handling of these async events needs to make a blocking call to send data over TCP and get a response before the next TCP data can be sent. E.G.

   ```
   procedure OnSerialPortRxChar(...);
   begin  
     if SendTCpData(...) = 'OK' then ...  
   end;  

   procedure OnTimerExpiry(...);  
   begin  
     if SendTCpData(...) = 'OK' then ...  
   end;
   ```

These should not interrupt each other, but currently do.

Obviously, my function `SendTCpData` needs some sort of blocking mechanism to prevent reentrant calls, or a queuing mechanism. Given that the caller needs to know the result, is my best solution a mutex?  The problem is that the TCP transaction is just one line in the 20 line `SendTCpData` function which those asynch events can invoke.

I hope that I have explained this comprehendably. If not, please request more information.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: A mutex is certainly too much as you do not need locking between processes. A critical section will do.

Comment: Make all the synchronous Indy calls from a single thread.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: that is just moving the problem to another place. You would still need some sort of queue or lock around whatever is going to hold the stuff for that thread to send...

Comment: @smasher (+1) a Mutex might be "too much", but it might also be the simplest to implement ... also I think that I do - in effect - "need locking between processes" (or, at least, threads), since the Serial Port component & Timer component appear to be running in their own threads (and posting messages to my app's Widnows message queue) .... continued in next comment for size reasons...

Comment: They are asynch and several can occur in quick succession, before the synchronus TCP transaction is complete. The problem is that the TCP transaction is just one line in a 20 line function which those asynch events can invoke.  I am no expert, which is obviously why I ask, but could that not be construed as a case for a Mutex?

Comment: @David (+1) "Make all the synchronous Indy calls from a single thread" - my app has only one thread (-ish). The the Serial Port component & Timer component appear to be running in their own threads (and posting messages to my app's Widnows message queue) and I don't see hwo I can change that.  I know little of threading or Mutexes, which si why I ask for guidance - hope you can help ...

Comment: @marjan Not really. Putting all comms into a single thread serializes the comms which is what is needed. In order to make comms feel async then a queue would be needed. Naturally that would need to be threadsafe.

Comment: I am assuming that the serial library is AsyncPro. If this is the case the AsyncPro events will run in the main thread irrespective of what thread invokes the AsyncPro queuing commands.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: putting all comms in a thread is not what serializes sending the messages. You would then still need to serialize / protect access to that thread('s messages to-be-send queue)... Which is not to say I would not use a separate comm thread (I do), only that using such a comm thread is just moving the serialization / simultaneous use protection from the Send function to another place.

Comment: @marjan a single thread executes code in serial and not in parallel. That's all I mean. Nobody can reasonably disagree with that statement.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: ah! Of course, yes, comms are serialized in that thread. I just understand "sending the messages" to be the whole sh'bang and not just the actual comms. And, I missed the closing "Naturally that would need to be threadsafe." in your previous comment. Reminder to self: don't shoot from hip, take breath, re-read, then keep pistol at hip...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TIdAntiFreeze. Just drop it on your main form. Your call will still be blocked but your GUI will not be blocked. You may want to use some timeouts with your client though.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to reply, thanks. I already use AntiFreeze. The problem is that those asynch events (serial port & timer), are all calling a 20+ line function which sets some stuff up, sends the TCP data & waits for a reply, catches exceptions, etc and the whole function needs be treated as atomic not just the INDY tcp send call.

Answer (score 1):

If your serial library is AsyncPro, I would go with a single-threaded solution. There is more than one way to skin a cat, and I am not saying that you could not use a multi-threaded solution. But given that the AsycPro events will be running in the main thread, and you are not currently using threading in your application, this may be the simplest way forward.

In this solution we use a re-entry gate and a queue. The following is a mix of Delphi and pseudo-code.

```
var
  isInTCP: boolean = False;

function DoSendTCP: boolean;
begin
isInTCP := True;
try
  result := SendTCpData(...) = 'OK'
finally
  isInTCP := False
end
end;

procedure OnSerialPortRxChar(...);
// This is safely re-entrant.
begin  
  repeat
    if isInTCP then
        Push the event onto a queue
      else if DoSendTCP then
        // Calling DoSendTCP may cause re-entry.
        etc...
        ;
    if (queue is empty) or isInTCP then break;
    Pop from head of queue
  until False 
end;
```

Comment: +1 for taking the time to reply, thanks. "If your serial library is AsyncPro ..." - alas, it is not

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is your serial library? (Disclaimer - I am the administrator of the AsyncPro project.)